# Как отследить время выполнения программы на Python?

Tags: python, время

Есть функция. Нужно отслеживать время выполнения функции в реальном времени. То есть: выполняется функция и как только время выполнение функции превышает, скажем, 4 секунды, выполнение функции прекращалось

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1359467/7485582

Answer (score 2, accepted):

нормально прервать можно только процесс multiprocessing/subprocess

```
import multiprocessing, subprocess, time

def target():
    time.sleep(10)
    print(target)

def process_with_timeout_terminate(timeout: float, func: 'callable', *args, **kwargs):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    p.start()
    p.join(timeout)  # Wait until child process terminates
    if p.is_alive():
        p.terminate()  # Terminate process; sends SIGTERM signal or uses TerminateProcess()

def programma_with_timeout_terminate(timeout: float, programma: str, *args):
    p = subprocess.Popen([programma, *args])
    try:
        p.wait(timeout)  # Wait for child process to terminate; returns self.returncode.
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        p.terminate()  # Terminates the process.

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_with_timeout_terminate(timeout=4, func=target)
    programma_with_timeout_terminate(timeout=4, programma='notepad.exe')
```

Если же требуется прервать выполнение в главном процессе или в потоке, то прервать функцию можно только если она генератор, т.е. в процессе своего выполнения она что-то возвращает используя yield. В этом случае прервать ее можно, но только после выполнения любого из таких yield. Однако слудкет помнить, что время которое может пройти между срабатываниями yield, может быть и больше timeout, т.е. не факт что прерывание выполнения произойдет точно в то время, как вы хотите.

```
import time

def target():
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        print(target)
        yield

def generator_with_timeout_terminate(timeout: float, func: 'callable', *args, **kwargs):
    t = time.monotonic()
    for _ in func(*args, **kwargs):
        if (time.monotonic() - t) >= timeout:
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generator_with_timeout_terminate(timeout=4, func=target)
```

Если требуется просто получить время выполнения куска кода или функции

```
import contextlib, time, datetime

def func(s):
    time.sleep(s)

@contextlib.contextmanager
def get_time():
    dt = {'start': datetime.datetime.now(), }
    try:
        yield dt
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        dt['stop'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        dt['execute'] = (dt['stop'] - dt['start']).total_seconds()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with get_time() as dt:
        func(3)
        func(2)
        time.sleep(1)
    print(dt)  # {'execute': 6.001126б 'start': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 30, 11, 33, 7, 521648), 'stop': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 30, 11, 33, 13, 522774)}

    t = time.monotonic()
    func(3)
    func(2)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(time.monotonic() - t, 'сек')  # 6.0 сек
```